# Passing value from multiple iframes to parent window before submit

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, hash

I am passing the value from 1 iframe to parent window before submit using location.hash, it works perfectly for 1 iframe, but I have 4 iframes and I need to keep the iframes apart:

Iframe1 I have:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function update(val) {
     parent.location = document.referrer + "#" + val
}
</script>
```

Parent I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val="";
function passVal(){
    if(location.hash != val){
    val = location.hash;
    val = val.substring(1, val.length);
    document.form.val.value=val;
   }
}
setInterval(passVal,200);
</script>
```

Works perfectly in 1 iframe - How do I do to pass the values from 4 different iframes to 1 parent window before submit? For example:

```
iframe 1 - VAL1 -> parent.window [field1]
iframe 2 - VAL2 -> parent.window [field2]   
iframe 3 - VAL3 -> parent.window [field3]
iframe 4 - VAL4 -> parent.window [field4]
```

All before submitting the form.

Thanks

Comment: For loop will not be your solution?

Comment: any suggestions? I tried clearInterval but still changing any of the 4 iframes set same value to all 4 fields in the parent.window

Answer (score 1):

Frame - here frame 1

```
function update(val) {
   parent.location = document.referrer + "#field1:" + val
}
```

Parent

```
var val="";
function passVal(){
    if(location.hash != val){
    val = location.hash;
    val = val.substring(1, val.length);
    var parts=val.split(":");
    document.formname.elements[parts[0]].value=parts[1];
   }
}
setInterval(passVal,200);
```

Comment: Perfect! I spent 2 days trying a solution before posting here - thank you!!